# How do I remove flickering from my HTML page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mockup here

http://dummytest.herokuapp.com/

At the moment the plain vanilla HTML shows first and then it flickers and it is rendered with CSS applied.  How can I get my page to show the CSS styling as the first thing completely bypassing the unstyled text?

Comment: You should clean your html code first: you have multiple doctype, head and body element. see http://html5.validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fdummytest.herokuapp.com%2F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to correct your HTML to comply with [HTML standard](http://validator.w3.org/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Test Harness</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <meta name="description" content=""> 
    <meta name="author" content=""> 
    <!--<Le>HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements</Le>--><!--[if lt IE 9]> 
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]--><!--<Le>styles</Le>--> 
    <link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="/stylesheets/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <style>body { 
        padding-top: 30px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */ 
    } 
    </style> 
    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/slimScroll.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="/javascripts/housefix.js"></script>  
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-transition.js"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-alert.js"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>     
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-modal.js"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-tab.js"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-popover.js"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-button.js"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script> 
    <script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
</head>  
<body> 
    <p> 
        <a href="/">Home</a> |  
        <a href="/login">Log In</a> 
    </p> 
    <h2>Welcome! Please log in.</h2> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your document is not [well formed (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element), which is leading to this behavior.

Generally web pages go:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <!-- meta tags go here along with title, 
      script links, and css style references -->
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- elements for rendering go here -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all your `<head></head>` code in one place and all your `<body></body>` code in one place as well.
Currently you have 2 sets of `<head>` and `<body>`. Take the one above (with menu) and merge it with the one below (with welcome message).

It would be best to run all your webpages through http://validator.w3.org/ to avoid future problems like this.